# Creating editable child from parent Angular data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a native way to do something like this in Angular?  I know of ng-repeat, but not sure how to implement it in this instance.

Basically, it would duplicate Id Number with an increased number e.g, 1001, 1002, etc and be able to create a new Name.

So:

Id Number: 1000
Bob
Id Number: 1001
Sue
Id Number: 1002
Rumplestiltskin

### Form Data:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Enter Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  <br />
  <div id="data">
    Id Number: {{num}}
    <br />Name: {{name}}
  </div>
  <form ng-submit=incNum()>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="New User">
  </form>
</body>
```

### Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.num = 1000;
  $scope.incNum = function ()
  {
    $scope.num ++;
    $scope.data.clone();
  }
});
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qH4cv6wCbnFRMUA9sVFh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally. This is where Angular shines. Just add an object into an array and let ng-repeat do the work. Try this out.

HTML

```
Enter Name: <input type ="text" ng-model="name"> <br />
<div id="data">
  Id Number: {{num}}<br />
  Name:  {{name}}
</div>
<form ng-submit=addUser()>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="New User">
</form>
<div ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}: {{user.id}}</div>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.num = 1000;
$scope.users = [];

$scope.addUser = function () {
  $scope.num++;
  $scope.users.push({
    name: $scope.name,
    id: $scope.num
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice!  What is this procedure called within angular?  Data binding?

Comment: Repeating the Id Number: 1001 Name: Bob is important.

Comment: @Sethe23 yup. It is databinding. You get to push stuff into an array and let angular update the DOM for you, through the ng-repeat directive. Accept the answer if it works for you ;)

Comment: Just waiting on that explanation.  Thanks for the help!